# How to add ca.crt ie certificate inside the docker executor of gitlab runner?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to add certificate in docker executor of my gitlab runner. I am facing various issues while doing this.
Can someone help me with how to do it?

Comment: Please clarify and add extra information of what you are trying to accomplish and what you have already tried.

Comment: are you using shared runners?

Comment: I am trying to push an image on a private repository. It is failing during the docker login into the private repository with an error as certificate assigned by the unknown authority . We are using shared runners.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a file on the gitlab runners and don't want to put that file into your repository e.g. for security reasons:

You can use [environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) for that.

You can set these in the gitlab GUI (Settings --> CI / CD --> Environment Variables)

Copy the content of ca.crt and set it as a value for an environment variable. You can then use that environment variable inside your pipeline file to write the content into a file ca.crt which you can create during the pipeline and put it where it is needed. After creating the environment variable in gitlab you may use it like the following inside the pipeline file:

`- echo "$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME" > /path/where/you/want/to/put/ca.crt`

Comment: I am not able to figure out the path where I want to add the certificate. I am using the docker executor.

Comment: @ShivangiBhardwaj did you figure this out?